# kubernetes default scheduler PVC not found

Tags: kubernetes-pvc

My jenkins pod is pending with the following error that PVC not found. but when I can check that the PVC does exist. I have provided the command outputs below. the pvc is getting provisioned in NFS what could be the issue. thanks in advance for any inputs

```
    kubectl describe pod jenkins-0
       Reason            Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  66s (x1715 over 21m)  default-scheduler  persistentvolumeclaim "g2-jenkins-azure-test" not foundnter code here

kubectl get po  
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-0   0/2     Pending   0          1h

kubectl get pvc  
NAME                    STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
g2-jenkins-test-azure   Bound    pvc-f036f668-d5fb-11ec-9210-000d3a58f73d   10Gi       RWO            nfs-client     29d

kubectl describe pvc g2-jenkins-test-azure  
Name:          g2-jenkins-test-azure
Namespace:     g2-jenkins-test-azure
StorageClass:  nfs-client
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-f036f668-d5fb-11ec-9210-000d3a58f73d
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: cluster.local/nfs-nfs-client-provisioner
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      10Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
Used By:       <none>
Events:        <none>
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: g2-jenkins-azure-test
  namespace: g2-jenkins-azure-test
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: nfs-client
```

Comment: There's a typo, you show us a PVC "g2-jenkins-azure-test" (yaml), and some "g2-jenkins-test-azure" (get pvc). While I'm not sure this is your actual issue / code snippet doesn't make sense. Please make sure to properly sed names.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. where could i correct the pvc name so pod can look for correct pvc

Comment: You're sure you're not missing something with those names? The `persistentvolumeclaim "g2-jenkins-azure-test" not found` can only mean one thing: there is no such PVC in jenkins'  namespace.